# postfix warning messages: override earlier entry

Tags: postfix

I have configured postfix with satellite configuration. I found the following warnings in my syslog. Any idea what it means? How could I resolve this problem?

```
Jul 16 13:39:24 mou-lanister postmulti[2042]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:24 mou-lanister postmulti[2046]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:24 mou-lanister postmulti[2053]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:24 mou-lanister postmulti[2057]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:24 mou-lanister postmulti[2061]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:24 mou-lanister postmulti[2063]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:24 mou-lanister postmulti[2065]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:24 mou-lanister postmulti[2069]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:25 mou-lanister postmulti[2095]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:25 mou-lanister postfix[2096]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:26 mou-lanister postfix/master[2101]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:27 mou-lanister postfix/master[2131]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:27 mou-lanister postfix/master[2131]: daemon started -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Jul 16 13:39:27 mou-lanister postfix/qmgr[2137]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
Jul 16 13:39:27 mou-lanister postfix/pickup[2136]: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 43: overriding earlier entry: relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
```

And what does the following e-mail mean? Is it some kind of configuration error?

```
Mail Delivery Subsystem

Jul 15 (1 day ago)

to me
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     root@lanister.net

Technical details of permanent failure:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=7720
[(0) lanister.net. [2a00:15f8:a000:5:1:12:5:e733]:25: Connection refused]
[(0) lanister.net. [2a00:15f8:a000:5:1:14:5:e733]:25: Connection refused]
[(0) lanister.net. [2a00:15f8:a000:5:1:11:5:e733]:25: Connection refused]
[(0) lanister.net. [2a00:15f8:a000:5:1:13:5:e733]:25: Connection refused]
[(0) lanister.net. [90.156.201.116]:25: Connection refused]
[(0) lanister.net. [90.156.201.80]:25: Connection refused]
[(0) lanister.net. [90.156.201.52]:25: Connection refused]
[(0) lanister.net. [90.156.201.94]:25: Connection refused]

----- Original message -----

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;
        h=from:to:auto-submitted:subject:message-id:date;
        bh=jPtDRVzcgGYkh/FpSbXMrZddqJD8VpLcMvdNka7tHvA=;
        b=xpTgoC+0TV6IMA667iDG4Up4aWCjFDsDZbCAzX5NcBr4fukSsYcpaxfIAmAb1lLC7m
         eqdiUWJCfoBUARXlQi7NdhxBp2r9JnLbzZ2+E15Fwh57Ldpw6uwW1DqKt8Z/rrCDGuq6
         BLqwBPyp26KLKQQRiRCEw//0di8AUauy0fS4DLYX91XyYuABSbzfmflW1CbDk0tgBrSj
         0o/ng1dDWUAiPURxknLyAg/wu1oSY7mXA6hdbN2EuwqF5I0K4ww6JCGw/5it/HNzRWPI
         Dk5B4dOcPeTTRO+66dVtwW1us/4kbOmm7jUNdrpbm3a78ZBU9GSnWUGmZC6mr0IfTsWZ
         jfWA==
X-Received: by 10.50.77.48 with SMTP id p16mr11423986igw.41.1405165154249;
        Sat, 12 Jul 2014 04:39:14 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <myusername@gmail.com>
Received: from mou-lanister (mydomainname.net [my-external-IP])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id vk3sm4844593igb.17.2014.07.12.04.39.11
        for <root@lanister.net>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 12 Jul 2014 04:39:12 -0700 (PDT)
From: myusernamename@gmail.com
X-Google-Original-From: mou@lanister.net
Received: by mou-lanister (Postfix, from userid 1000)
        id B505C1480086; Sat, 12 Jul 2014 07:39:08 -0400 (EDT)
To: root@lanister.net
Auto-Submitted: auto-generated
Subject: *** SECURITY information for mou-lanister ***
Message-Id: <20140712113908.B505C1480086@mou-lanister>
Date: Sat, 12 Jul 2014 07:39:08 -0400 (EDT)

mou-lanister : Jul 12 07:39:08 : mou : 1 incorrect password attempt ; TTY=pts/5 ; PWD=/home/mou ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/apt-get install ircii
```

Comment: Can you please send your /etc/postfix/main.cf ? [(0) lanister.net. [90.156.201.116]:25: Connection refused] ... means that mail server (gmail) is unable to connect to lanister.net MX server (SNMP)
it looks like this mail server is unreachable.

Answer (score 9):

Probably in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file, you have defined:

```
relayhost=smtp.gmail.com
```

and then you have redefined it like so:

```
relayhost=
```

To solve this issue, you will need to remove those duplicates.

**None:** Before making any changes, create a backup of your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file.

Answer (score 4):

do a

```
$ grep -R "relayhost" /etc/postfix/
```

this would give you idea where you have defined an empty relayhost in your postfix configuration files.